# Advantages of workflow based software development vs normal programming based software development

Tags: functional-programming, workflows, bpmn

I am very new to workflows, and trying to understand why workflows are used. While surfing internet, I haven't found any strong point for using workflows.

Please explain me the scenarios where workflow based development has advantage in comparison to usual programming based development.

my project is using BPMN 2.0 diagrams and xml based BPMN.

Answer (score 6):

<sup>Following Doc Brown's advice, I've cobbled together an answer from the comments I had posted on this page.</sup>

In my experience, the theoretical selling point behind workflow systems is that you don't need software developers to use them or update them. You simply point your Business Analyst or Subject Matter Expert at them and *voila!*, you have a working system.

In practice, however, they are a painful mess to use because their main users rarely ever think about code reuse, code maintainability, or even source control.  Anything written in them quickly becomes an unreadable mess that nobody wants to touch.

The only people who seem to like workflow systems are their salespeople and the suckers who bought one :P

Answer (score 5):

They're cool and they're new and (most importantly) some companies decided they were expensive and attracted a large amount of commission to anyone who sold them. Hence we went through a period where workflow engines were de rigeur.

Unless you have specific and tightly focussed requirements where a workflow engine would be beneficial, they are terrible things to use. The complexity of a solution built using a workflow product increases exponentially in my experience. The cost of doing the same thing using normal development tools is much cheaper and easier to maintain.

Comment: Agreed.  In my experience, the only people who like workflow systems are their salespeople and the suckers who bought one.

Answer (score 1):

Workflow modeling and workflow tooling allow *someone* who knows what they are doing to model the process of moving work products.  This surprisingly hard problem is usually orthogonal to the application that supports it, and often needs to be revised at times where it is not convenient to deploy code.

There's different levels of workflow tooling:

- **All-in-one package:** UI editing rules and workflow all rolled in to one product.  They are usually only useful for prototyping efforts.
- **Workflow libraries (like open source Activiti):** they understand the BPML markup, and only handle the transitions from one stage to the next
- **Custom systems:**  Everything that relates to workflow is controlled by proprietary software, and require a software release to make changes to the workflow portion
- **Hybrid systems:** Custom software for the UI that makes use of a Workflow library.  Provides the custom integrations real systems need, and allows the workflow to be tweaked outside of a release cycle.

It's actually really hard to get workflows done well.  It's easiest to implement a custom system or to prototype with an all-in-one package.  It's most difficult to get a hybrid system working well--particularly if your action screens vary step by step.